# Facebook PHP SDK help to get users friend list?

Tags: facebook

I am a beginner.I just extracted facebook php sdk files in root of my site.
I created a app and got app id and secret from developers account.
I want u to help me to connect to facebook using php sdk and get a users friend list.
Please help me i was unable to find tutorial for this elsewhere

Comment: And you didn't find https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

Comment: In Facebook API v2.0 /me/friends will only return friends that are also using the app. Not all friends

Answer (score 0):

Download and install **hybridauth**. This is available here: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

After install it (just open in browser for installation and follow the steps) use the preferred social media( `facebook, twitter, googleplus  etc` are available ) and sign in.

Here you have to fill the requisted thing like `app id`, `secret id` etc.

After signing here you were redirected to a `profile page`. There you will get the required information.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I got this error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: @BrainyPRB, when you got this error?while creating app id or something else?

Comment: While using a example for facebook login /join included in it